# C# unable to check if user exist in SQL Server table

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Lately I have been trying to learn SQL as well on how I can connect my C# application to retrieve and send info (like usernames and passwords) since last night I have been trying to check if a user exist inside the table or not when I perform my SQL commands on the SQL Server they return the correct result, however whatever my application does it won't work

Code

```
public int CreateUser(string Username, string Password)
{
        try
        {
            SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) from users where username like @username", connection);
            sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", Username);

            int userCount = (int)sqlcmd.ExecuteScalar();

            if (userCount > 0)
            {
                return 1;
            }
            else
            {
                MakeUser(Username, Password);
                return 0;
            }
        }
        catch (SqlException e)
        {
            strErrorMessage = e.Message;
            throw;
        }
}
```

PS: for everyone who said the connection needs to be open. It's open

Comment: Do you have any error? I think you forget to open your connection. Add this code before SqlCommand: `connection.Open();`

Comment: What is the message (if any) stored in your _strErrorMessage_ ? Looking at it will shed some light on your problem

Comment: Do not learn bad habits first and foremost. Stop using [addwithvalue](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/).

Comment: @SMor thanks i was unaware of how bad Addwithvalue can be now that i know what it really does

Comment: @Steve i have been checking and theres no error to be found it just won't work

Comment: Supposing you have your connection correctly open somewhere (and this is a really bad practice) can you show your connection string? Do you use the shortcut |DataDirectory| to reference your database? Also I suggest to use the debugger and check what exactly is contained in the UserName variable when your code tries to prepare that parameter

Comment: @Steve this is my connection string Server=KALKI\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=AZaZeDB;Trusted_Connection=True;

Comment: @JohnDoe try this `string ConnectionString = @"Data Source=KALKI\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=AZaZeDB;Integrated Security=True";`

Comment: You act on the count result as if it were a boolean so IF EXISTS is a more efficient alternative that does not involve actually having to count rows.

Answer (score 1):

It may be that you are trying to query for a partial username but the query doesn't have '%' . Unless you pass exact username, query will not return any record.

Answer (score 1):

ExecuteScalar requires an open Connection

```
connection.Open();
int userCount = (int)sqlcmd.ExecuteScalar();
connection.Close();
```

Comment: the connection have been opened somewhere else already so thats certainly not the problem because i am able to change it to like "INSERT INTO" and it will create a new record with whatever values i want

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned above, execute scalar requires a valid open connection to execute correctly.

In addition, your SQL statement includes a like, however, there are missing % from the statement so unless the username existed explicitly in the table it would never return a value.

For example;

```
SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM users where username LIKE '%doe%'
```

This will return a count of all users in the user's table where the username is like **doe** at any position in the username column, you could have a username of **johndoe** and the above statement would return 1 as **doe** exists in the column.

You can find out more about the [SQL Like Operator](https://www.w3schools.com/SQL/sql_like.asp) here

Here is the amended code which should do what you want.

```
public int CreateUser(string Username, string Password)
    {         

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Con))
        {

            con.Open();

            try
            {

                SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) from users where username like '%' + @username + '%'", con);
                sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", Username);
                int userCount = (int)sqlcmd.ExecuteScalar();
                if (userCount > 0)
                {
                    return 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    MakeUser(Username, Password);
                    return 0;
                }
            }
            catch (SqlException e)
            {
                String strErrorMessage = e.Message;
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Adding the wildcards could result in false positives. IE you return 1 when the user doesn't exists because the wildcards matched a similar user. The OP approach is correct because it consider only the differences in case

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know what the fault is but i tried everything and now it works. for those who have the same problem this is my current code
Thanks everyone

```
string connstring = @"Data Source=KALKI\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=AZaZeDB;Integrated Security=True";

public int CreateUser(string Username, string Password)
    {

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connstring))
        {

            con.Open();

            try
            {

                SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) from users where username = @username", con);
                sqlcmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@username", Username));
                int userCount = (int)sqlcmd.ExecuteScalar();
                if (userCount > 0)
                {
                    return 1;
                }
                else
                {

                    return MakeUser(Username, Password);
                }
            }
            catch (SqlException e)
            {
                string strErrorMessage = e.Message;
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Also note that `SqlCommand` is also IDisposable so should also be in a `using` block.